# TensorFlow: Does rebuilding an installed TensorFlow from source cause any internal problems?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently running TensorFlow training on an AWS P2 instance which has tensorflow 0.12 installed. I upgraded it to 1.0 using pip, but if I want to configure it from source and rebuild it using bazel in order to improve the CPU computation speed (according to suggestions given whenever I run TF), would this be possible? Or do I have to uninstall TF and rebuild from scratch?te

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the your CPU potential you should compile it with the correct flags and reinstall.

Following this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

I use, for my concrete case:

```
bazel build --config=opt --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse3 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Meaning to say can I just use `./configure` on my current tensorflow directory to reconfigure it and compile again using bazel?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just to clarify: your tensorflow directory, where you have the code it isn't your tensorflow installation.

Comment: The weird part comes in because I get a tensorflow 0.12 whl after configuring and building from bazel the wheel file. Is this because the original tensorflow I had was in 0.12, which meant the `./configure` file is meant for 0.12? Does this mean I have to reinstall tensorflow from scratch by deleting the whole tensorflow file?

Comment: If you are getting a 0.12 whI after compiling, obviously you have a 0.12 downloaded version of TF. I would start from scratch. The 'hard' part, which is compile whole tensorflow, has to be done anyway so: 'pip uninstall tensorflow' > 'git clone' the last version > './configure' and then install the built wheel. What's the difference between skipping the 'pip uninstall tensorflow' part and don't?

Comment: I see. I thought because I upgraded tensorflow to 1.0 from 0.12 through pip, I should get a 1.0 whl instead.

Comment: Well, actually you have an upgraded version installed, but this doesn't mean your 'git cloned' version (wherever it is) is also updated. I don't know if I'm explaining myself, sorry, what I mean is that you have TF 1.0 installed in your system (wherever you have python libraries) and you also have the cloned 0.12 git repo downloaded in other folder (maybe /downloads or maybe /desktop..)

Comment: Ah I see..meaning to say the tensorflow 1.0 configure file would not get downloaded through pip, and so I'm left with a 0.12 configure file although I am using TF 1.0, is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. You should clone that branch of the repository, configure it and then compile.